# I can't figure out how to convert sql query into ruby (Nesting selects)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to show the statics of some database on a webpage written in Ruby-on-rails. I know what do I have to ask the database, but i dont know how to write it in ruby.

The goal is to know how many users have done this 4 activities on the same festival.

The sql query i want to convert into ruby is:

```
`SELECT count(distinct usermail) FROM stats where festivalId='2013' 

and usermail in (select usermail from stats where typeActivity='checkins')

and usermail in (select usermail from stats where typeActivity='programs')

and usermail in (select usermail from stats where typeActivity='status')

and usermail in  (select usermail from stats where typeActivity='pictureUpload');
`
```

**So my problem is that I don't know how to nest this "selects" into the big one.** I have tried writing in the controller things like this without any success.

```
 def self.countTotalActivity(appId)

    stats= Stat.where(:festivalId => appId).where(:typeActivity => ('checkins').where(:typeActivity => 'status'))

    return stats.count
  end
```

I have been lurking in the documentation, and trying diferent things for days, but i don't make any progress...

Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't seem to yield what you say it should. It seems like you ought to have a `having count(typeActivity) = 4` or something to that order.

Comment: In short you want ruby query for `SELECT count(distinct usermail) FROM stats WHERE festivalId='2013' AND usermail IN (SELECT usermail FROM stats WHERE typeActivity IN ('checkins', 'programs', 'status','pictureUpload'));`

Comment: Yup. All subqueries need to have ` and festivalId='2013'` at the end

Comment: Sorry i misread your question, you want email which is common in all `'checkins', 'programs', 'status','pictureUpload'` and ` festivalId='2013'` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
stats= Stat.select(:usermail).where(festivalId: 2013,typeActivity: ['checkins','status', 'programs', 'pictureUpload']).uniq.count
```

Comment: thanks for answering! but this query is returning the sum of all fields where there are checkins or status or... but not what i wanted to do, that is: number of usermails who made all this 4 activities (see query above)... i need to know how the syntax is, how to nest this subqueries...Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
Stat.where("festivalId=? AND typeActivity IN (?)", '2013', ['checkins', 'programs', 'status','pictureUpload']).group('usermail').having("COUNT(DISTINCt typeActivity) = 4").count
```